# command-line argument problems

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am attempting to implement command-line options into my code. For some reason, my -a option works correctly, but my -c option does not work well, even though they are basically the same. I get the following message when I try to run my code with the -c option.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
Aborted
```

Below is my code.

```
int c;
std::string config = def+std::string("SamplesConfig.xml");
std::string cal = def+std::string("calibration.bin");
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "a:c"))>=0)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'a':
        {
            config = std::string(optarg);
            printf("%s", (char *)config.c_str());
            break;
        }
        case 'c':
        {
            cal = std::string(optarg);
            printf("%s", (char *)cal.c_str());
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce this at all? Do you know what line of code is actually throwing the error? Have you debugged it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be calling getopt("a:b:c:") ? I imagine as you've specified just c, optarg will be null when it gets to that point.

Comment: Thanks. This was the first time I've used command-line arguments, so I didn't realize that I need to end with a colon.

Comment: well, you don't need to, but omitting it means it treats 'c' as an option that takes no arguments. a:c: means -a takes an argument and -c takes an argument, whereas a:c means -a takes an argument but -c doesn't